# Changing the system header path and custom header files

Tags: c

```
gcc 4.4.5 c89
```

I recently downloaded and installed log4c on my development machine.
I put all the headers and includes in the following directories.

```
project_name/tools/log4c/inc
project_name/tools/log4c/libs
```

However, as I installed the headers where in the system path:

```
/usr/include/log4c/*.h
```

So in my project, when I was including layout.h. layout.h would include the following header in this system path.

```
#include <log4c/logging_event.h>
```

I created the same directory structure on the target machine as I did for my development for `tools/inc` and `tools/lib`.

However, it wouldn't compile because I hadn't installed the log4c on the target machine so the system path for log4c didn't exist. However, the user of the target machine will not be expected to install log4c. Everything should work out of the box.

So what I think is a good idea is to edit all the headers. from this:

```
#include <log4c/logging_event.h>
```

to

```
#include "logging_event.h"
```

All the headers are in the inc directory, so I won't be using the system path.

My question is this a good idea to put all the headers into a single directory and edit them to point to this single inc directory?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd leave the headers alone -- changing them is potentially error-prone and time-consuming, especially if you want to update your version of log4c at some point.

Am I understanding right that the same headers that are in `/usr/include/log4c` are also in your `project_name/tools/log4c/inc` directory?  If so, move them to `project_name/tools/log4c/inc/log4c`, and add an include path to your `gcc` command line using the `-I` flag:

```
gcc -I project_name/tools/log4c/inc myprog.c etc etc
```

We're moving the files to `log4c/inc/log4c` so that `<log4c/logging_event.h>` can still match on the `log4c` directory under `log4c/inc/`.

**EDIT**: I originally typoed `-L` as the flag, which sets library search paths rather than include file search paths. `-I` is the correct flag for this case.

Comment: The `-L` command adds a directory to the library search path, which is only used for finding libraries to link, not headers to include (see the man page http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)

Comment: @Jesse: Thank you!  I meant `-I`.  Correcting in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [log4c](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/) library comes with a directory structure

```
/src
  /log4c.h
  /log4c
     /lots of *.h and *.c
```

So it's designed to include its headers as

```
 #include <log4c.h>
```

or

```
 #include <log4c/logging_event.h>
```

as you've done. It's important to do things this way; if, instead, you just write

```
 #include <logging_event.h>
```

and you distribute your library to someone who has a *different* `logging_event.h`, the files may get confused, and your poor user will end up including the wrong file.

So I recommend sticking with the directory structure that log4c uses. In your case:

```
project_name/tools/log4c/inc/log4c/logging_event.h
```

etc. (as @Jander suggested). The proper way to add the include directory with gcc is `-I`:

```
gcc -Iproject_name/tools/log4c/inc foo.c
```